# How to know if a DB transaction is successfully committed?

Tags: database, transactions

For example, I execute commit() at the end of a transaction and wait for the response from the database. If for some reason, the waiting times out, how can I know if ***this transaction has been successfully committed and thus made durable by the DB***?

I supposed two possible reason for the timeout:

1. The commit() message is not delivered to the database.
2. The commit() message is well deliverd to the database but for some reason not processed by the DB.
3. The commit() message is well delivered to the database and processed by the DB, but for some reason, the response from the database cannot be delivered to my client application.

Answer (score 0):

try to surround it with try catch did you close connection after the statement ? 
Post some code that we can help you